# How to develop a scheduler date application using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval, schedule

I have a *noob doubt* about **how to code this scenario** using **JavaScript**.

> Develop a data structure to help scheduling airplanes to take off and
>   land from this runway.
>
> Each time a plane takes off or lands, it needs exclusive use of the
>   runway starting 10 minutes before the scheduled runway use, and ending
>   10 minutes after the scheduled runway use (assume the actual take-off
>   or landing is instantaneous).
>
> Be sure that planes don’t have overlapping schedules.

1. The Scheduler class will be call using ReactJS.
2. The class needs to be tested as well using babel and mocha. (I care about that later)

I evaluated the use of `schedule.js` but this is not the case. I think to use `setInterval()` to schedule the time, but I don't know if it a good strategy.

The task is to implement a scheduler with approximately the following API:

```
class Scheduler {
    // returns true if there'ss room to schedule at `time`
    CouldScheduleAt(Date time)

    // returns true if we successfully scheduled
    ScheduleAt(Date time)

    // Choose an available time to schedule at, and return that time
    Schedule()

    // returns true if we successfully unscheduled something
    UnscheduleAt(Date time)
}
```

So.. How I can developer this scenario using JavaScript?

#### Edit - I implemented based on `Tiago Henrique` implementation.

```
class Scheduler {
    constructor(timer) {
        this.dates = new Set()
        this.planes = {}
        this.timer = timer
    }

    isPlaneInList(time) {
        return (time in this.planes)
    }

    isDatesInconflicting(scheduledDate, time) {
        if (time.getTime() <= scheduledDate.getTime()) return true

        return (time.getTime() > this.timer)
    }

    // returns true if there's room to schedule at `time`
    couldScheduleAt(time) {
        if (this.dates.has(time)) return false

        Object.keys(this.dates).map(scheduledDate => {
            if (this.isDatesInconflicting(scheduledDate, time)) {
                return false
            }

            return time
        })

        return true
    }

    // returns true if we successfully scheduled
    scheduleAt(time, plane) {
        if (!this.couldScheduleAt(time)) return false

        this.dates.add(time)
        this.planes[time.toString()] = plane

        return this.isPlaneInList(time.toString())
    }

    // Choose an available time to schedule at, and return that time
    schedule() {
        // ......
    }

    // returns true if we successfully unscheduled something
    unScheduleAt(time) {
        const plane = this.planes[time.toString()]
        if (!plane) return false

        delete this.planes[time.toString()]
        this.dates.delete(time)

        return !this.isPlaneInList(time.toString())
    }
}

export default Scheduler
```

I don't be sure about `isDatesInconflicting` implementation but there is for now. The `schedule` function there's nothing in this moment.

References:

- [Test runner about setInterval vs. setTimeout](https://jsperf.com/setinterval-vs-settimeout)
- [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/)
- [Chai - BDD/TDD assertion library](http://www.chaijs.com/)

Comment: Check out the Moment.js package for comparing dates.

Comment: Ow I liked Moment timer http://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/timer/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's no priority involved you simple need a queue where the dequeue method should wait for 20 minutes to dequeue the next item. This can be achieved using a `Promise` and `setTimeout`. e.g.

```
class PlaneQueue {
  constructor() {
    this.dequeueChain = Promise.resolve()
    this.planes = []
  }


  enqueue(plane) {
    this.planes.push(plane)
  }

  dequeue() {
    // this is returned to the caller so it gets the next plane
    const intermediateChain = this.dequeueChain.then(() => {
      return this.planes.shift()
    })
    // update the internal promise to resolve again only after 20 minutes
    // this will cause the next dequeue call to wait for 20 minutes
    this.dequeueChain = intermediateChain.then(() => {
      return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1200000))
    })
    return intermediateChain
  }
}


const planesQueue = new PlaneQueue()
planesQueue.enqueue({ name: 'Airfrance' })
planesQueue.enqueue({ name: 'American Airlines' })
planesQueue.enqueue({ name: 'Latan' })

planesQueue.dequeue().then((plane) => console.log(`${plane.name}: ${new Date()}`))
planesQueue.dequeue().then((plane) => console.log(`${plane.name}: ${new Date()}`))
planesQueue.dequeue().then((plane) => console.log(`${plane.name}: ${new Date()}`))
```

This works by taking advantage of the ability promises have to be `chain`. When we use `then` and return a new Promise inside it, the result is a new promise that fulfills only when all "chained" promises are fulfilled too.

The idea here is that we chain a new promise, that resolves after 20 min, every time `dequeue` is called, causing the next call to effectively have to wait 20min for the next plane, and so on.

**EDIT**

I didn't really see the API you were trying to follow at first, the code above will not fit in that case. What you need is a list of scheduled dates and a map to link dates with planes. To check if you can schedule something you will have to go trough all dates and check that there isn't a date less than 20 mins before or after.

```
class PlaneQueue {
  constructor() {
    this.dates = new Set()
    this.planes = {}
  }

  couldScheduleAt(date) {
    if (set.has(date)) return false
    for (scheduledDate of dates) {
      // check the date is not less than 20 minutes before or after
      if (conflicting(scheduledDate, date)) {
        return false
      }
    }
    return true
  }


  scheduleAt(date, plane) {
    if (!couldScheduleAt(date)) return false

    this.dates.add(date)
    this.planes[date.toString()] = plane
    return true
  }

  unscheduleAt(date) {
    const plane = this.planes[date.toString()]
    if (!plane) return false

    delete this.planes[date.toString()]
    this.dates.delete(date)
    return plane
  }
}
```

An even better approach would be to use a list structure that keeps its items in order, so you would be able to exit the loop early (you only need to go to the position where the new date would be placed and check if it is not conflicting).

How you'd use this inside a react component is not really important, as long as this schedule mechanism is correct you could use it anywhere, not just inside a react component.

Comment: Thank you for a contribution. That planes don’t have overlapping schedules.

Comment: The problem in this scenario is that I need to follow the life cycle of schedule that I mentioned above.

Comment: Sorry, didn't really pay attention to the API you're trying to follow. That would need different approach. In that case I'd say to keep a set of `scheduledDates` and a map linking the date with the plane. `CouldScheduleAt` will then have to go over all dates and check there is no date that is less than 20min before or after.

Comment: I think this line `intermediateChain.then(() => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time)))` should be call in the React component to check and unschedule after this time, right? 0.o